# How is it possible to set a default layout/no layout for certain MIME types in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, layout, rabl

I am generating json using [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). It is a bit disturbing and probably not the right way to set for json rending that it has no layout.. It naturally does not have and definitely not a HTML based one.

How can I make rails not adding layout for a json rendering? Or more generally, how to set a global strategy for layouting MIME types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked that but I think it will work:

```
class ApplicationController < BaseController
  layout :mime_layout

  def mime_layout
    case params[:format]
    when "json"
      false
    ....
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For the completion, the mime_layout should be a private method. Thanks for the help!